# I cannot find next() method from ResultSet instance

Tags: java, database, h2

I'm trying to do a query to an embedded h2 databases.

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(getDbUrl(), getDbUser(), getDbPassword())) {
    System.out.println(con.toString());
    
    PreparedStatement pStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
    
    ResultSet myRs = pStatement.executeQuery();

    return myRs;
}
```

I can get the ResultSet, but if i add a watch to the instance I cannot see next() method, from expressions tab in eclipse I can see a different object returned: rs0: org.h2.result.LocalResultImpl@3f56875e columns: 1 rows: 3 pos: -1

Inside of this object I see the result with a list of Rows [[Lorg.h2.value.Value;@60015ef5, [Lorg.h2.value.Value;@2f54a33d, [Lorg.h2.value.Value;@1018bde2]

How can I get the rows?

Thanks

Comment: When the flow of the code gets out of `try-with-resources`, the connection `con` is closed and thus related prepared statement and result set are closed too.

You need to populate some list/set/collection from the `ResultSet` and return this collection

Comment: I solved the problem with your tip thanks.